# Modify the number of interruption cat /proc/interruption

Tags: proc, interrupt

As you can see, when running the command `cat /proc/interrupts`, in the second column the number of interrupts delivered to each CPU per device driver.

```
test@test:~$ cat /proc/interrupts
           CPU0       CPU1       
  0:         79          0   IO-APIC-edge      timer
  1:          9      17152   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
  4:          2          0   IO-APIC-edge    
  6:          5          0   IO-APIC-edge      floppy
  7:          0          0   IO-APIC-edge      parport0
  8:          1          0   IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
  9:          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi
 12:     694613          0   IO-APIC-edge      i8042
 16:    1233922          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb3, ahci, nvidia
 17:       3961     168757   IO-APIC-fasteoi   uhci_hcd:usb4, pata_jmicron
 18:          0          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1, uhci_hcd:usb7
 19:         59          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ata_piix, ata_piix, uhci_hcd:usb6
 22:        819       6915   IO-APIC-fasteoi   HDA Intel
 23:          2          0   IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb2, uhci_hcd:usb5, eth
```

My question is how can I change the frequency of the number of interruptions?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

That's not how interrupts work. An interrupt means that something asynchronously happened and the CPU needs to go pay attention to it *now*. You can read a little more about it [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_request_(PC_architecture)).

Comment: Thank you. Actually, this is https://passthroughpo.st/config_hz-how-does-it-affect-kvm/ what I want. B/R

Comment: That's not a standard interrupt; that is the system timer.